# Lubuntu - Move panel across monitors

Tags: lubuntu, gui

Well, I switched to Lubuntu because Unity was too slow. How would I move the panel across monitors? I tried looking at the settings for the panel, but I can't move it across monitors. How can I acomplish this?

On a side note, what are some ways to snaz up Lubuntu and get a dark theme?

Comment: Have you right clicked the panel? I'm pretty sure there's an option to move it.

Comment: Oh, there's a monitor section.

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click in the panel and select "Panel Settings", on the "Geometry" tab, there is a "Monitor" selection box. This allows you to choose which monitor the panel displays on, and also has an "All" option, which will stretch it across multiple displays. There doesn't appear to be a way (in this settings UI) to duplicate it on every display, but this covers most use cases.

Answer (score -1):

Extending the lxpanel across two monitors can be done easily,  See http://lxlinux.com/#14.  It has a step by step explanation of how to set up your two monitors and the lxpanel either on the bottom or the top of the screens. To establish dual monitors with LXDE, install Arandr from Synaptics. Arandr can set-up placement, orientation and resolution for each monitor. Before saving, set up the geometry of any horizontal panels. For a bottom panel across both monitors, align the bottoms of the displays as in the image on the right; for a top panel, align the tops. A second horizontal panel can be only set-up on the display whose unaligned edge is outermost, since any extension onto the smaller display will be hidden. Otherwise, the horizontal placement and geometry in general can be achieved in the usual way. For an lxpanel, right click an open spot on the panel and choose Panel Settings.
With regard to your second question, there are several themes that have a dark appearance.  Try them all.  Menu->preferences->Openbox Configuration Manager.

Comment: Please at least include a summary of what is to be found in the link. The question is not very broad. Also, and more important; links tend to disappear or change.

Comment: As requested a summary of what is included in the link was added to the answer.